# W3.CSS Trying to Create a Cascading Dropdown from a Dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, w3.css

I am using the W3.CSS menu system to create a dropdown from a hamburger icon.  The problem comes when I am attempting to create a cascading dropdown from one of those menu items.  I have tried a number of variations and can't see to get it right.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<body>
    <div style="display:block-inline;float:left" id="iconMenu" class="w3-container">
        <div class="w3-dropdown-hover">
        <button class="w3-button w3-blue-gray"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars fa-2x"></i></button>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border">
        <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Home</a>
        <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
        <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 2</a>
        <button class="w3-button">Dropdown Again <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
```

```
        <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```